# How to post attachments to mattermost from jenkins ? ex: log file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, mattermost

I am able to send url of the log but attachment is not working
getting below error:if i use attachments variable

WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'jenkins.plugins.mattermost.workflow.MattermostSendStep': attachments

Comment: why you have decided attachments are supported by this plugin?

Comment: Is there any other workaround ?

Comment: you could write own code to use upload file api https://api.mattermost.com/#operation/UploadFile. or provide just a link to a log file location in a text message.

Comment: Url of log file is working  but challenge is to download it. let me check. thanks!!